# Is it valid HTTP to send a 406 with the client request has no Accept header

Tags: http

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2 states that

> A request without any Accept header field implies that the user agent
> will accept any media type in response.

Also https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html states that

> If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the
> client accepts all media types. If an Accept header field is present,
> and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according
> to the combined Accept field value, then the server SHOULD send a 406
> (not acceptable) response.

Still, would it be *wrong* to send back a 406 Not Acceptable in such case ?
In particular we want to enforce the customer to write client code that is version aware (our Content-Types have a version modified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it be wrong to send back a `406` Not Acceptable in such case?

The short answer is **yes** and the answer is in your own question. Once RFC 2616 is no longer relevant, consider the quote from the RFC 7231:

> A request without any `Accept` header field implies that the user agent will accept any media type in response.

The same paragraph of RFC 7231 states in which situation the `406` status code can be used:

> If the header field is present in a request and none of the available representations for the response have a media type that is listed as acceptable, the origin server can either honor the header field by sending a `406` (Not Acceptable) response or disregard the header field by treating the response as if it is not subject to content negotiation.

See how the [`406`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6) status code is defined:

> [**6.5.6.  406 Not Acceptable**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6)
>
> The `406` (Not Acceptable) status code indicates that the target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request (Section 5.3), and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

Comment: But a generic 400 could still be sent, regardless ?

Comment: @PaulPraet That's probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be wrong for compliant servers. A missing accept header should be treated the same as accepting all content-types. That doesn’t mean you can’t still reject a missing accept header, since many security tools already do:

- [Abyss Guard](https://www.abyssguard.com/wiki/features/headers-check/)
- [ModSecurity](https://serverfault.com/q/377656/3150271)
- [Bad Behavior](https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/admin-tools/Ticket/9925-what-does-the-message-required-header-accept-missing-means.html)

If you want to stay compliant, you could send a [400 error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) which is generic, but 406 error would make more sense.